# What is the best technique to find out which package breaks due to using unsupported features?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I'm working on a project that fails to run on IE11 due to use of unsupported arrow functions. There are quite a lot dependencies and I'm not sure what's the quickest / easiest way to find out which uses arrow functions?

Comment: You might just integrate Babel into your build process to automatically transpile ES6+ syntax to ES5. (polyfills too, if needed)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way by doing a search in file for `=>` inside the built items. There are comments before each transpiled block showing the source module name.